# Custom error status code with gqlgen + go gin

Tags: go, error-handling, graphql, go-gin, gqlgen

Recently I have been updating my GO REST APIs into [graphQl API's](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) and I came across issue where I am unable to customise my status code with gqlgen.

Response I got

Headers

```
Status Code: 200 OK
```

```
{ 
data: null,
errors: [
  {message: "Unauthorized access", path: ["..."]}
]
}
```

Expected Header

```
Status Code: 401 UNAUTHORISED
```

Any help would be really appreciating!

Answer (score 5):

Assume you have a `gqlgen` resolver similar to this:

```golang
func (r *queryResolver) SecretItems(ctx context.Context, userID string,
    password string) ([]SecretItems, error) {
        // ...
        if !isAuthorized(userID, password) {
                return nil, errors.New("Unauthorized access")
        }
        // ...
}
```

then the described behavior is expected. Errors should be returned as part of
the response body.

GraphQL is transport agnostic. While it is often served over HTTP, it might be
served over other client-server Protocols as well. Handling errors in the
response body requires no assumptions about the protocol. Hence, you shouldn't
rely on HTTP status codes.

Handling errors in the response body has another advantage: Assume a request
contains multiple queries. Some of them succeed, some of them fail. Then the
response can contain the result of successful queries under `data` and errors
related to failed queries under `errors`.

References:

- [GraphQL website](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#response)
- [Specification: Response](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Response)
- [Hasura: GraphQL vs REST](https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/intro-graphql/graphql-vs-rest/)

## Possible reason why you expected a 401 status code

The `gqlgen` [docs on
authentication](https://gqlgen.com/recipes/authentication/) contain an example
where 401 status code is returned.

Why? This happens in a http handler used as *middleware on the chi http server*.
The 401 status code is *not* returned by a GraphQL resolver.